# CakePHP redict to other url from view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to redirect to other view from view.ctp .

Suppose like this =>

```
if($val == 0 ) {
  redirec to 'posts/index'
}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/982/redirect, but do it in the controller.

Comment: What reason is there to redirect from the view‽

Comment: I have a column mark. if the mark = 0 then no post will be displayed. Empty white page is being displayed if i do http://mysite/posts/view/1 but for this i want to redirect to other action. I don't need to display white empty page. if the mark = 0 for postid=1 then you can't hit http://mysite/posts/view/1 to display post. how can i do this ?

Comment: You should already know whether mark will be 0 in the controller. If not, there's something wrong with your design.

Comment: 'mark' is a column from posts and comments table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do redirection in the controller, not in the view. Period.
You can do the same check you're doing in the view in the controller easily.

I don't know about your specific situation, but I usually use this pattern:

```
public function view($id) {
    $post = $this->Post->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Post.id' => $id, 'Post.mark' => 1)
    ));
    if (!$post) {
        $this->cakeError('error404');
        // or redirect, or show a more specific error page, or do something else
    }

    $this->set(compact('post'));
}
```

This way the check you need to do is handled on the database level, were it belongs, and the redirect/error is handled in the controller, were it belongs. The view is much too late in the request cycle to check for business logic like *"is the user actually allowed to see this?"*, the job of the view is only to output information.